# Added unit testing target to Xcode - failed to import bridging header won't go away

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, bridging-header

I added a new Test target to my Xcode project. My project has Swift code and Objective-C code, and has a bridging header. Upon either adding the bridging header to UnitTesting's build settings, or doing `import MyTarget`, I'm getting the error:

> failed to import bridging header

I've tried:

- Adding the bridging header to project, unit testing and main target's build settings.
- Changing `defines modules` to `Yes`.
- Moving the bridging header file to the root folder.

I've also tried making a sample project, which built and worked fine. Taking everything I have over into a clean new project isn't an option at this point.

Comment: Did you get any progress with this? I have the same problem...

Comment: @ManuelM. add `${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2` to project's Header Search Paths. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: it didn't work I am afraid... :(

Comment: @ManuelM. did you find a solution?

Comment: @swalkner it got solved with further versions of Xcode. Eventually it worked. I don't really know what I did different, sorry. I think I added some needed Frameworks in the bridging-header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue testing and using Cocoapods in a Swift project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495225/issue-testing-and-using-cocoapods-in-a-swift-project)

Answer (score 55):

If you use CocoaPods as package manager, must set search path etc. Give a simple way,

Try adding this in your Podfile:

```
target 'YourProductTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
end
```

and `pod install`

It works for me.

If the above solution does not work for you, try setting manually:

1. Click your Test target -> Build Setting-> tab: All & Combined -> Swift Compiler -Code Generation -> Objective-C Bridging Header : add your xxx-bridging-header
2. Check "Search Path", set up value of `Framework Search Path`, `Header Search Paths`, `Library Search Path` according to your main target. Maybe some search path lose here, manually add again.

Comment: Second option worked for me. Wasn't using CocoaPods.

Comment: This works. is this thing documented anywhere ? how can i find more about why we have to use `inherit! : search_paths`

Comment: cannot thank you enough for this solution! worked like a charm!

Answer (score 21):

@Victor Choy solution works for me, but I had to move test target inside product target like so:

```
target 'YourProduct' do

   # Pods for product

   target 'YourProductTests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      # Pods for product testing
   end
end
```

This did not work for me:

```
target 'YourProduct' do
   # Pods for product
end

target 'YourProductTests' do
   inherit! :search_paths
   # Pods for product testing
end
```

Comment: Yes., ur solution is worked. If u know reason, pls do comment

Answer (score 11):

I faced the same problem. I did the following and the issue of 'Failed to import bridging header' is solved.

Steps:

1. Select your project -> Build settings -> Search for '**Defines module**' -> give 'YES'
2. Copy Objective-C bridging header path
3. Select your test target -> Build setting -> Swift compiler - General -> Objective-C bridging header -> Give Bridging header path.
4. Make sure '**Header Search Paths**' of test targets contains all the headers in ios Targets. Add them if any of the headers are missing.
5. Build.

Reference: [Refer this link.](http://forum.cocos2d-objc.org/t/setting-up-xctests-with-swift/17298)

Comment: Unfortunately that link is obsolete.

Answer (score 7):

This may be useful for someone: if the Unit Test target is added to an existing project which already includes CocoaPods and some Objective-C library pods.

Below steps solved the ***Failed to import bridging header*** issue.

1. Select your Project -> Build Settings -> Search for 'Defines module'
       -> give 'YES'
2. Copy Objective-C Bridging Header Path from 'YourProduct' target and
       paste it in the 'YourProductTests' target's bridging header path.
3. Podfile should have 'YourProductTests' target inside 'YourProduct' and should include the _inherit! :search_paths_ like below

...

```
target 'YourProduct' do
   # Add Pods for your product here...

   target 'YourProductTests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      # Pods for product testing, if any
   end
end
```

4. Then perform '**pod install**' from the root folder of the project. This fills the *Header Search Paths* for 'YourProductTests'.
5. As a last step verify that both 'YourProduct' and 'YourProductTests' target's *Header Search Paths* should be similar.

Answer (score 6):

At this point, I've never had to `import MyTarget` to get unit tests to work in Swift.

**Common Solutions**

- I assume you tried it, but it wasn't clear if you added your bridging header to your app target and test target at the same time?
- Another option, that may not be ideal, is to add a bridging header in your test target so that you actually have 2 bridging headers. They should look the same and would be a good test.
- If using `$(SRCROOT)` to reference your bridging header path, ensure it is being evaluated to correct path.
- If all else fails, you should do file diff of your `.xcodeproj` with the one of your working project and match any relevant values that might be different.

The bridging header system isn't perfect, but here are a few issues I've run into.

Answer (score 1):

For me, on a project without Cocoapods, I had one place, indistinguishable from other similar tests, where this warning would just not go away. I had a bridging header for the tests, but it was empty.

What cleared it for me, was going to the **tests target > Build Settings > Objective-C Bridging Header** and hit the delete key (should clear the link to the header file).

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the Objective-C bridging header from the existing project to the unit test set will still be an issue in 2024. If you have a project and decide to add module tests to it at some point, the Xcode will not see the existing Objective-C bridging header.
To fix such an issue, one must manually register the path to the bridging header.

I want to show you my existing project as an example. I created a copy of the bridging header in the testing directory of the project, renamed it accordingly, and then put the path to the testing bridging header into the test settings.

Creating a header copy is unnecessary, but you can, and it will work.

I am adding the screenshots to match the settings of the existing project with the registered header compared to the new testing environment without the header file registration.

Please observe the existing project settings. The Objective-C bridging header is registered in the "Swift Compiler - General" sub-section of the "Build Settings" section.

[image]

Then, if one adds the unit tests to the project, the Xcode does not fill the related setting value. It is empty.

[image]

We need to manually fill in the setting value according to the header file path.

[image]