# How to fix @testable import failed to load module in xcode unit testing

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, cocoapods

I had created an Xcode project without unit testing. I have added cocoa pods when I try to create a new unit testing and try to import @testable import 'ProjectName' it gives an error  Failed to load module 'ProjectName'. can u please help me out to solve the problem

@testable import 'ProjectName' Failed to load module

Comment: Same as here. Did you solve this error?

Comment: @Capotasto Yes I have solved it

Comment: @Capotasto please remove unittest and re add the unit test file

Comment: I have solved this error as well. Thanks! In my case, I just run a test build ignoring the error that import failed to load module then it works and the error is gone.

Answer (score 15):

Update Podfile like this and check

```
target 'App' do
  pod 'Alamofire'

  target 'Demo AppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

  end

  target 'Demo AppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

  end  
end
```

Comment: @CamScen I had to run `pod install` after changing the file. Also, I had one target that needed adding, not two

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is not solved after trying @Naveen's answer and you have Obj-c bridging-header in your main target, you should create another briding-header with the same values for your tests.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to clean the build folder. You can find this under: Product > Clean Build Folder. (shortcut: shift + cmd + k)