# Failed to load module 'project name'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, testing

I added unit test target to my existing project, but while `@testable import Product_Module_Name`
getting error  "Failed to load module 'Product_Module_Name'".
**I tried** https://stackoverflow.com/a/58164638/17664589 but it is not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on scheme -> Edit scheme -> select Test -> under info select Build configuration for which Enable testability is Yes. this solved my issue.