# Xcode 6.4 Swift Unit Test Won't Compile: "GPUImage.h not found" "failed to import bridging header"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, unit-testing, travis-ci

My Xcode project **builds and works fine**. It has Swift and Objective-C code.

It has GPUImage installed.

*I added a unit test to it and now it will no longer compile:*

> 'GPUImage.h' file not found
>
> Failed to import bridging header

Here are the workarounds I have found and tried:

1. **Setting the Product Module Name to match my project:** *Didn't work*
   http://codesheriff.blogspot.co.il/2015/05/importing-swift-code-from-objective-c.html
2. **Ensured my build phases matched**: *Didnt work*
3. **Expanding the header search paths**: *Didnt work*
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/29902874/3324388

This question seems to  have the same issue:
[added unit testing target to xcode - failed to import bridging header won't go away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343493/added-unit-testing-target-to-xcode-failed-to-import-bridging-header-wont-go-a)

If you know why XCode can't find my BridgingHeader.h or GPUImage.h then please share. I am trying to get Unit Testing working with Travis CI but can't get passed the compile step.

Answer (score 1):

`Xcodebuild` doesn't properly support test targets and application tests. I'd try [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool), which is a nice alternative to `xcodebuild` and makes it easier to test iOS and OSX apps. Travis CI comes with it pre-installed.

To install it locally on your machine, you can use homebrew.

```
update brew
brew install xctool
```

You can use the following command to build your code. Its structure is identical to `xcodebuild`.

```
xctool test -workspace MyExampleProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyExampleTests -sdk iphonesimulator
```

To run it on Travis CI, add the following code to your `.travis.yml`

```
language: objective-c
script:
  - xctool -workspace MyExampleProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyExampleProject -sdk iphonesimulator
  - xctool test -workspace MyExampleProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyExampleProjectTests -sdk iphonesimulator
```