# Xcode: failed to import bridging header with non Debug or Release configuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode7

I have a project in Swift and importing some custom frameworks. I have added another configuration (testing). When I build for Debug or Release configuration I have no issues with the bridge header. But if build for testing configuration. I get the error "failed to import bridging header"

Any of you knows why this is happening with a non debug/release configuration?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: I've had this problem for a while: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150012/xcode-6-4-swift-unit-test-wont-compile-gpuimage-h-not-found-failed-to-impor

Comment: Have you manually added bridging header in build settings for test configuration?

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan when I generate the test configuration I duplicate my debug configuration. What you mean Have you manually added bridging header?

Comment: Oh then its ok. I mean don't forget to add it here - https://monosnap.com/file/1j8UeoX021SQCqQ3iRkCKweUifNbCl

Comment: @EvgenyKarkanthe bridging header are showing for al the configuration Release/Debug/Testing

Comment: And even for tests target? I guess you are using it right?

Comment: What you mean test target?, the bridging header file?

Comment: Oh, never mind, I thought you are using unit tests target - https://monosnap.com/file/ionm0k4m9av7CZSIVvZMo2xWtV93Eg

Comment: @user2924482 I'm facing the same issue now. Have you managed to fix it?

Comment: @MaksTheAwesome, did you make sure add the bridging header to your test target : https://monosnap.com/file/ionm0k4m9av7CZSIVvZMo2xWtV93Eg#

Comment: @user2924482 Well with targets, everything works fine but first I wanted to use one extra build configuration which was the problem. I have a sample project where it works but for some reason the issue remains for me so I made a workaround and created a target for each configuration I need.